# Is it safe to assume that STL vector storage is always contiguous?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

If you have an STL vector which has been resized, is it safe to take the address of element 0 and assume the rest of the vector will follow in memory?

e.g.

```
vector<char> vc(100);
// do some stuff with vc
vc.resize(200);
char* p = &vc[0];
// do stuff with *p
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**Yes, that is a valid assumption (*).**

From the C++03 standard (23.2.4.1):

> The elements of a vector are stored
>   contiguously, meaning that if v is a
>   vector where T is some
>   type other than bool, then it obeys
>   the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for
>   all 0 <= n < v.size().

(*) ... but watch out for the array being reallocated (invalidating any pointers and iterators) after adding elements to it.

Comment: If you're using a draft standard, or anything not yet ratified and official, please say so.  I couldn't find anything like that in the current standard.

Comment: In the C++0x draft, it's 23.2.5.1, and in C++03, It's 23.2.4.1.  The wording is not in the C++98 standard.  I'm looking at ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)

Comment: It was added later in the Technical Corrigendum.

Answer (score 27):

The C++03 standard added wording to make it clear that vector elements must be contiguous.

C++03 23.2.4 Paragraph 1 contains the following language which is *not* in the C++98 standard document:

> The elements of a `vector` are stored
>   contiguously, meaning that if `v` is a
>   `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is
>   some type other than `bool`, then it
>   obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] +
>   n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`.

Herb Sutter talks about this change in one of his blog entries, [Cringe not: Vectors are guaranteed to be contiguous](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/):

> ... contiguity is in fact part of the
>   vector abstraction. It’s so important,
>   in fact, that when it was discovered
>   that the C++98 standard didn’t
>   completely guarantee contiguity, the
>   C++03 standard was amended to
>   explicitly add the guarantee.

Comment: +1: This is the answer. It is only safe to assume since with 2003-compliant implementations, not "always".

Answer (score 14):

Storage is always contiguous, but it may move as the vector's capacity is changed.

If you had a pointer, reference, or iterator on element zero (or any element) before a capacity-changing operation, it is invalidated and must be reassigned.

Answer (score 10):

[Yes it's contiguous](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html#faq-34.3)

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector` guarantees that the items are stored in a contiguous array, and is therefore the preferred replacement of arrays and can also be used to interface with platform-dependent low-level code (like Win32 API calls). To get a pointer to the array use:

```
&myVector.front();
```

Answer (score 2):

yes.

it should alway be contiguous