# In-built Sorting in C++

Tags: c++, c

How do use vector or in-built sort function in C++ with most of the language in C? I am trying to just sort an array for a C program. Can it explained with a simple code with sort implementation? I am very new to C++.

Comment: C or C++? I guess the first step is to realize that's they're two different languages...

Comment: If you are getting c-style array, you can convert it to `std::list` and then use `std::list::sort` and then convert it back (if you need to). Conversion is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087582/converting-stdlist-to-c-friendly-type

Comment: @DanielSaska AFAIK `std::sort` works in C-style arrays without any further work. Even if you did have to copy it into a standard library container, using a vector would be at least as simple, run faster, and use less memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`std::sort`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) has a code example:

```
std::array<int, 10> s = {5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3}; 

// sort using the default operator<
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
for (int a : s) {
    std::cout << a << " ";
}   
std::cout << '\n';
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: I think it's preferable to use non-member `begin()` and `end()` with c++11.

Comment: @Mithrandir can you explain why?

Comment: You can read it up in quite a few paleces, the basic are: non-member begin and end work with all stl containers and arrays and can be overridden for any other container one has no possibility to alter, hence make for better generic programming.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to sort in `C` then you should use [qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

If you want to sort in `C++` then you should use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: Also, `std::sort` is perfectly capable of working on ordinary C arrays, while the inverse (`qsort` sorting STL containers) doesn't hold.

Comment: @user4815162342 That is true. The reason I put both of there is because OP isn't very clear on which compiler he has. I'm guessing he has a C++ compiler but he also says `just sort an array for a C program.`

Comment: @Caesar Well, if it's a C program there won't be any C++ standard containers in sight, so that's not exactly a problem. The wording of your answer is spot on, the choice depends on the language/compiler, not on whether you have a C or C++ data structure.

Comment: Without input from the OP this is only guesswork, but the OP might be working on a C codebase where he is implementing newer parts in C++. The interfaces are still C linkage and data structures, but the implementation of individual components can use STL and other C++ facilities internally. This setup is fairly common when using C++ to interface to large C frameworks such as GTK or CPython.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a qsort example for sorting strings that sorts and prints the passed arguments:

```
#include <string.h>

static inline int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
   return strcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    qsort(++argv, --argc, sizeof(char *), cmp);
    while (argc){
      write(1,argv[0],strlen(argv[0]));
      write(1,(--argc && argv++)?"\t":"\n",1);
   }
}
```

for other types just replace the strcmp with a-b in the cmp() function and swap the order to change ascending vs. descending.

Answer (score -1):

This method used built in sorting algorithm and changes its time complexity based on the input array.

```
 1. #include <bits/stdc++.h>
        using namespace std;

        int main()
        {
            int arr[] = {1, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0};
            int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
           sort(arr, arr+n); //sort(arr, arr+n, greater<int>()); for descending

            cout << "\nArray after sorting

 using "
             "default sort is : \n";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            cout << arr[i] << " ";

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged.