# std::vector vs std::array performance

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, c++-chrono

I was looking at the new chrono library (C++11) and trying to use it. I wrote the two following programs:

**vector.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vector(1000000, 0.);

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i(0); i < vector.size(); i++)
    {
        vector[i] += 1.;
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-start).count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**array.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::array<double, 1000000> array;

    std::fill(array.begin(), array.end(), 0.);

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i(0); i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        array[i] += 1.;
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-start).count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I obtained 9 millisecond for the array program and 12 milliseconds for the vector program. The  std::vector seems about 33% slower than the std::array. I'm doing it right? Why this difference?

Ps: I'm using GCC 4.7, Mac OS X 10.7.

```
g++-mp-4.7 -std=c++11 vector.cpp -o vector
g++-mp-4.7 -std=c++11 array.cpp -o array
```

Comment: Change to `for(int i(0), iMax( vector.size() ); i < iMax; i++)`.

Comment: Did you run it enough times to ensure your times are statistically accurate? - 3ms difference in 1 run might not be meaningful.

Comment: @Ylisar Why? I tried to write exactly the same code for both the containers.

Comment: @R.M., to make sure that you are not doing any extra work on every iteration - you should do it for both versions.

Comment: @John3136 I tried 10 times (how I create a script to execute the programs 10000 times and save the results?) and array.cpp give always 9-10 millisecond and vector.cpp 12-14 milliseconds...

Comment: As an aside, you don need `std::fill` to zero the array, you can initialize it like this `std::array<double, 1000000> array{}`.

Comment: You should also switch on optimization, otherwise the exercise it completely academic.

Comment: with -02 timings are the same for me on gcc; clang somehow fails and the difference persists

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intrinsic array access is much faster than std::vector access -- Black Magic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092855/intrinsic-array-access-is-much-faster-than-stdvector-access-black-magic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [efficiency of c++ arrays vs std::vector and std::array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954493/efficiency-of-c-arrays-vs-stdvector-and-stdarray)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I changed your code to this:

```
std::array<double, 1000000> array;

double total = 0;
std::fill(array.begin(), array.end(), 0.);

for (unsigned j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        array[i] += 1.;
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    total = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
}

std::cout << total << " for Array." << std::endl;

std::vector<double> vector(1000000, 0.);
total = 0;

for (unsigned j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
    {
        vector[i] += 1.;
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    total = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
}

std::cout << total << " for Vector." << std::endl;
```

My results using `-O3`:

```
8123 for Array.
8117 for Vector.
```

Seems to me that both are equally fast.

Comment: I confirm your results (with the O3 option): 3005 for Array.
3018 for Vector. For 10000 cycles: 30103 for Array.
30082 for Vector.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers are meaningless without enabling optimizations. Most likely the repeated calls to size() make the difference in your case.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::array` has a size known at compile time, so the memory will most likely be allocated on the stack.

A `std::vector` uses `std::allocator` (which probably uses `new to allocate memory from the free store (aka the heap) at runtime).

I would say 30% is normal for heap vs stack allocation.

---

**EDIT:** Running this a couple of times (not the most scientific measurement, I know) on liveworkspace.org ([`std::vector`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/d7c8557af27c0dfac870e89520161e44) and [`std::array`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/098dc4d43c4308da7c23731417c314c9)), I get 8 vs 10 ms. As all allocations are indeed outside the measurement, I would naively conclude that accessing the heap is slower than accessing stack memory. I wouldn't be surprised if this is generally true, as there is an extra indirection in the case of the heap.

Comment: All allocation happens outside the timing window.

Comment: It is clearly not allocating 1M doubles on the stack - guess again.

Comment: @lucas1024 so you think `std::array` knows about anything else than the stack?