# std::vector(n, std::vector(n)) or std::vector(n*n)?

Tags: c++, stl

1. What way to store n.m matrix is more efficient? To create a vector of n vectors of size m or to a create big vector of size n.m?
2. How is a vector of vectors stored in the memory? Does it contains only references/pointers or whole vectors?

Comment: I would prefer `std::vector<>(n * m)`. The vector itself is a structure of fixed size which stores size, length, and a pointer to data memory. The data memory is (re-)allocate on heap whenever resizing beyond capacity is requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's more efficient to use a single vector of size N x M.  This way all the memory is contiguous, and there is only a single pointer to all of it, rather than N pointers.
2. A vector of vectors is stored as a pointer to an array of pointers, each of which points to an array of values.

Comment: Apparently, the answer is not as obvious. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093860/using-nested-vectors-vs-a-flatten-vector-wrapper-strange-behaviour.