# Are there any benchmark programs (suite) for performance comparisons of C++ vectors and Regular arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, runtime, benchmarking

I am looking for a set of **benchmark programs** which use **dynamic arrays** (**vectors**).

I am **comparing** the **performance** of **programs** in using **vector** and **regular arrays** (with **manual resize**).

This is on top of **additional functionality** of **vector** to **dynamically resize at runtime**

Comment: may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988617/stl-containers-speed-vs-arrays - long story short: stop thinking that you can outperform stl-containers from the start and only worry about rewriting them to old school array pointer thingsies if you struggle real performance issues. For your performance test, why dont you write a simple one yourself? Also this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kQnCS.png

Comment: One fairly simple/rudimentary comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2203174/179910