# Destructor for array of pointers to arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, destructor

Ok, I have this constructor:

```
Board::Board(int nRows, int nCols){
    numRows=nRows;
    numCols=nCols;

    int** board=new int*[numRows];
    for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
        board[i]=new int[numCols];

        for(int j=0; j<numCols; j++){
            board[i] [j]=-1;
        }
    }
}
```

where board is an array of the number of rows where each item in the array points to an array of length of the number of columns, so this board is set up and initialized to values of -1. My question is how I'm supposed to implement my destructor for a case like this, I understand the concept of the creation of each array of pointers, but in destruction I'm still a little lost. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `std::vector` or a more efficient wrapper for a 2D one and you won't need a destructor (or the other required members to deal with that array).

Comment: Simple rule : Use `delete []` or `delete` as many times you called `new []` or `new` respectively

Comment: Gross, dude.  Just gross.

Answer (score 5):

First point: don't do it. Just don't. Use an `std::vector` to store the data, and user operator overloading to allow the client to use 2D dimensions to index into it.

That said, you'll probably insist on doing it anyway, so you might as well do it as well at least know the basic idea: take your original `new`s, and invert them so to speak. So, you started with:

```
int** board=new int*[numRows];
for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
    board[i]=new int[numCols];
```

Inverting that, you start by deleting the individual items:

```
for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++)
    delete [] board[i];
```

Then you delete the outer pointer:

```
delete [] board;
```

I'll repeat though: it's much cleaner to just use a [`std::vector` for the storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6465254/179910).

Comment: I would love to use vectors, I understand vectors, but I'm not allowed to use vectors for this class. 'Preciate the help

Answer (score 2):

For everything you allocated with `new[]`, call a `delete[]`, and for everything you allocate with `new`, call `delete`.

You're doing one top-level `new[]` allocation (so one `delete[]` for that) and another `numRows` `new[]` allocation, each requiring their own `delete[]`.

The order should be reversed for deallocation.

The actual code is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You are better of using `std::vector<std::vector<int> >;`

But here's what you need

```
for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
        delete[] board[i];    //Delete each row allotted inside the for loop
    }
 delete[] board;         //Delete the row/array of pointers
```