# C++ : Data Structure withe fast searching and less memory requirements

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to know which data structure will be memory efficient in my case.Please guide me. Following are the requirements. As shown in the fig below, on the basis of three values A, B and C ( where A will be an integer value and B , C will be characters) I want to store two values accepting rule number and true/false.Thus, for each unique value of A,B and C I want to store two values (accepting rule number and true/false) corresponding to them.Please guide me which data structure will be fast in searching and will also be memory efficient.As in my case the table length can go upto 65025 or above.

[image]

Comment: It is absolutely unclear how table on the left corresponds to the table on the right - please explain.

Comment: Maybe you should look at in-memory database like SQLite

Comment: Does memory efficient mean packing or speed?

Comment: @woolstar By memory efficient , I mean that it should not consume much memory and along with that it should be fast in searching.

Comment: In your example, input left table has all unique combinations. Is it always true? Can rows in that table repeat? If not, there are better ways...

Comment: Why the concern with memory footprint?  If you "store two values (accepting rule number [integer] and true/false [bool])", that is 5 bytes, times 100 000 elements (to round up your estimate), or 0.5 MB.  If you store the integer and two chars as well, you are looking at approximately 1 MB, plus container-related data.  These are not big memory demands on modern PCs.  If you're developing for something truly memory-limited, or need to have multiple data structures, please correct me.

Comment: @mvp the rows in left table will always be unique. Please do mention which ways will be better in my case.

Comment: @Zara: it seems that A is simply ordinal number, and as such does not need to be explicitly stored. Rule number also seems to be locked to A. In the end, all you want to store is chars B, C and boolean field active. If your chars B, C can be only lowercase letters, you need only 5 bits for each. Total is 5*2+1=11 bits, or just 2 bytes. You can store 64K array of these in 128KB, and use simple binary search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious possibilities in the standard library would be `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`. For `std::map`, you'd create some class holding `A`, `B` and `C`, and define a comparison function for that class. For `std::unordered_map`, you need to define a hash function instead.

For fast searching (and little or no interest in the speed of insertion and deletion) you might also consider using a vector sorted on the A, B, and C fields. This will typically improve speed *and* reduce space used compared to `std::map`. The disadvantage is that insertion and deletion become linear instead of logarithmic (i.e., slower--potentially quite a lot slower, especially when the collection is large).

As far as which of these to prefer: if you were working with large enough tables that the big-O complexity was likely to dominate, then `std::unordered_map` would be the obvious choice--it gives constant (expected) complexity. `std::map` gives logarithmic complexity. The sorted vector would be logarithmic as well if you used only a binary search. Assuming your keys are distributed reasonably, you could use an interpolating search, which normally has roughly O(log log N) complexity. log log N grows *very* slowly--so slowly it's often called "pseudo-constant" or something similar. IOW, even for tremendously huge tables, there's not much reason to believe hashing will necessarily be significantly faster.

Big-O analysis is most relevant to *much* larger tables though (say, hundreds of millions, rather than the tens of thousands suggested in the question). For the table size your suggesting, a logarithmic search algorithm might well be entirely competitive. For example, up to 65536 items, we expect no more than 16 comparisons for a binary search.

A lot then comes down to balancing memory use with search speed. If you're willing to sacrifice some space to get better search speed, a hash table (`std::unordered_map`) is probably the obvious choice. If you're more concerned with minimizing memory usage, then the sorted vector probably wins. `std::map` is probably the easiest of the three to implement, and (given the size you're talking about) its speed probably won't be a significant problem either (but the other two *will* probably be faster).

Comment: My table length would be significantly high and its important for my algorithm to search fast but at the same time it should not exhaust the memory. So, should I prefer std::unorderedmap (as hash can be fast in searching)??

Comment: @Zara: I've added some more information on choosing between the three to my answer.

Comment: `unordered_map` gives constant complexity if the base table is wide enough to contain all the data and if the hash function modulus the base table size will never give same results. If you cannot predict in a reasonable way what size you'll have to deal with, may not be "ideal" (and will never be "constant") The `map` will probably be the best compromise between memory and performance, The vector for memory (and performance if it does not change too often).

Comment: @JerryCoffin In one of the similar problems, I am making use of 2D array.As you mentioned that vector is fast in searching but insertion is slow then should I prefer vector over 2D array? because in my case searching speed is important not the insertion speed.

Comment: @Zara: In most cases, instead of a 2D array, I'd use a simple wrapper around a vector to provide 2D addressing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6465254/179910

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of exactly what you mean by memory efficient, but a data structure like the following would certainly work:

```
struct my_data
{
  int accepting_rule;
  bool true_false;
};

std::map<std::tuple<int, char, char>, my_data> my_map;
```