# Allocating an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix

I'm hitting an odd segmentation fault that is happening somewhere and I was wondering whether it could be due to the way I allocated the matrix array of pointers.

It's declared as such in the .h file:

```
int **matrix;
```

But when I pass it, I am using it in this way int *matrix[], in order to
access individual rows with matrix[i] (this made a lot of my tasks simpler).

So, when I am allocating the matrix, should I have done:

```
matrix = new int * [vertices];
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
         matrix[i] = new int[vertices];
```

Or for the third line, should I use the -> operator:

```
   matrix[i]-> new int[vertices];  // Or something like this.
```

And what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Can you post more code, like the function that receives the matrix argument? And maybe post a small, compilable example.

Comment: One compiles and the other doesn't?

Comment: The file is huge, this is just sections of it that I am worried may be causing the fault. @0x499602D2 well, yes, hence the comment next to it...

Comment: I think you're looking for the operator `*` rather than `->` in the latter example.

Comment: `matrix[i]= new int[vertices];` is fine. I suggest compiling and running it.

Comment: Just to clarify C++: the operator -> means (*a).b On the other hand matrix[i] is the position i, you don't need anything else there

Comment: @FabricioPH: When `matrix` is (or decays to) a pointer, then `matrix[i]` is the same as `*(matrix + i)`.

Comment: I'd approach the job task differently. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6465254/179910

Comment: As an option to an array of pointers for a matrix, you could do a single allocation for the matrix and set a pointer to the first row of the matrix:  int (*pmatrix)[vertices] = (int( * )[vertices]) new int[vertices*vertices]; ... delete [] pmatrix; This makes pmatrix[0] a pointer to the first row of the patrix, pmatrix[1] a pointer to the second row, without using an array of pointers.

Comment: is that a cast operation @rcgldr?

Comment: Separating the statements: int (*pmatrix)[vertices]; - this declares a pointer to an array of (vertices) integers. Then pmatrix = (int ( * ) [vertices]) new int[vertices*vertices] ; allocates vertices^2 (squared) integers (to be used as a matrix of vertices rows by vertices columns), and casts the pointer returned by new to be compatible with pmatrix.

Answer (score 0):

The first option you suggested is completely fine in this case. But the second one with the `->` operator is not even a valid syntax. The first line from the first suggestion actually creates an array of `int*` of size *vertices*:

```
matrix = new int * [vertices];
```

Each of the elements of this array is initialised with some garbage values. You can make sure it is initialised with zero by using braces like this: `new int * [vertices]()`. But in either case accessing any of the pointers by `matrix[i]->` would be meaningless. In fact the arrow operator `->` is a dereference operator that is used exclusively with pointers to objects that have members. Hope that helps.