# How to clear a matrix declared like this -> vector<vector<int>>

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I want a fast method to clear(set a matrix with 0 everywhere) a matrix of type `vector<vector<int>>`, just simple as the initialization was:

```
vector<vector<int>> values(nr_rows, vector<int>(nr_cols, 0));
```

Can I do this without a `for`?

Comment: IMO, you're probably starting from the wrong place. Is there a good reason you can't provide 2D addressing of a single vector instead? For example, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6465254/179910. With that as a starting point, it's pretty trivial to add a `clear` member function if you see fit (not necessarily a good idea, but easy anyway).

Comment: A first improvement would be continuous memory - as @JerryCoffin suggests

Comment: I have a signature of a function that I am not able to modify and it's vector<vector<int>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
values.assign(nr_rows, vector<int>(nr_cols, 0));
```