# How do I access the internal contiguous buffer of a std::vector and can I use it with memcpy, etc?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

How can I access the contiguous memory buffer used within a std::vector so I can perform direct memory operations on it (e.g. memcpy)?  Also, it is safe to perform operations like memcpy on that buffer?

I've read that the standard guarantees that a vector uses a contiguous memory buffer internally, but that it is not necessarily implemented as a dynamic array.  I figure given that it is definitely contiguous, I should be able to use it as such - but I wasn't sure if the vector implementation stored book-keeping data as part of that buffer.  If it did, then something like memcpying the vector buffer would destroy its internal state.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to assume that STL vector storage is always contiguous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247738/is-it-safe-to-assume-that-stl-vector-storage-is-always-contiguous)

Comment: @Bo, may not be a dup as the OP here asks specifically about C std lib functions whereas the linked question does not.

Comment: The dup shows `char* p = &vc[0]` as the way to get at the buffer. Then what?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In practice, virtually all compilers implement `vector` as an array under the hood. You can get a pointer to this array by doing `&somevector[0]`. If the contents of the vector are POD ('plain-old-data') types, doing `memcpy` should be safe - however if they're C++ classes with complex initialization logic, you'd be safer using [std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/).

Comment: The standard guarantees the vector to be a contiguous block.

Answer (score 10):

Simply do

```
&vec[0];

// or Goz's suggestion:
&vec.front();

// or
&*vec.begin();
// but I don't know why you'd want to do that
```

This returns the address of the first element in the vector (assuming `vec` has more than `0` elements), which is the address of the array it uses. `vector` storage is guaranteed by the standard to be contiguous, so this is a safe way to use a vector with functions that expect arrays.

**Be aware** that if you add, or remove elements from the vector, or [potentially] modify the vector in any way (such as calling `reserve`), this pointer could become invalid and point to a deallocated area of memory.

Comment: Or &vec.front() which is much much nicer than your begin method above ;)

Comment: Nps :)  I tend to prefer using it to using &vec[0] as it makes it far far more obvious that I'm using a vector :)

Comment: why not vec.data()?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do:

```
  &vect[0]
```

The memory is guaranteed contiguous so its safe to work with it with C library functions such as memcpy. However, you shouldn't persist pointers into the contiguous data because vector resizes may reallocate and copy the memory to a different location. IE the following would be bad:

```
  std::vector<char> charVect;
  // insert a bunch of stuff into charVect
  ...
  char* bufferPtr = &charVect[0];
  charVect.push_back('a'); // potential resize
  // Now bufferPtr may not be valid since the resize may have moved
  // the vectors contents
  bufferPtr[0] = 'f'; // **CRASH**
```

Answer (score 2):

```
&myvec[0]
```

But note that using `memcpy` is really only applicable if this is a vector of PODs or primitive types.  Doing direct memory manipulation of anything else leads to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use `&v[0]`, where v is your vector.  An example:

```
int write_vector(int fd, const std::vector<char>& v) {
   int rval = write(fd, &v[0], v.size());
   return rval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - since the standard guarantees contiguous placement of the `vector`'s internal data, you can access a pointer to the first element in the vector via:

```
std::vector<int> my_vector;
// initialize...

int* arr = &my_vector[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can safely read  the right amount of data from the underlying storage, writing there may not happen to be a good idea, depending on the design.

```
    vlad:Code ⧴ cat vectortest.cpp
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
        using namespace std;
        vector<char> v(2);
        v.reserve(10);
        char c[6]={ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
        cout << "Original size is " << v.size();
        memcpy( v.data(), c, 6);
        cout << ", after memcpy it is " << v.size();
        copy(c, c+6, v.begin());
        cout << ", and after copy it is " << v.size() << endl;
        cout << "Arr: " << c << endl;
        cout << "Vec: ";
        for (auto i = v.begin(); i!=v.end(); ++i) cout << *i;
        cout << endl;
    }
    vlad:Code ⧴ make vectortest
    make: `vectortest' is up to date.
    vlad:Code ⧴ ./vectortest
    Original size is 2, after memcpy it is 2, and after copy it is 2
    Arr: Hello
    Vec: He
    vlad:Code ⧴
```

So if you are writing past the `size()`, then the new data is not accessible by class methods.

You can account for that and ensure the size is enough (e.g. `vector<char> v(10)`), but do you really want to make software where you are fighting the standard library?