# How to Convert a (vector of pointers) --> (Pointer to an array of pointers)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I understand "[How to convert vector to array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c)"

answers how to convert a vector of doubles (NON POINTER TYPE) to an array.

> My requirement :: To convert  (a vector of CustomClass pointers) to (a CustomClass pointer to an array of CustomClass pointers).

**Does the following code mean "(vector of pointers)  --> (Pointer to an array of CustomClass pointers)"**

```
std::vector <CustomClass*> vectorObject(SizeOfVector);  // Here each element of the vector //is a pointer to CustomClass object.
CustomClass* customClassArray = &vectorObject[0];
```

Please correct me if I am wrong. Kindly Help with a code snippet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector is a wrapper in a sorts for an array and provides all the features of an array whilst also allowing the array to grow shrink know how big it is and a lot of other useful features.  One of the requirements of std vector is that its data is stored in a contiguous fashion like an array.  Because of this requirement you can get an array of elements by taking the address of the first element regardless of type.

`std::vector <CustomClass*>vectorObject` Means that you have a vector of CustomClass Pointers to get an array

`CustomClass **Array = &vectorObject[0]` Now I have taken the contiguous data segment at offset 0 in the vector and assigned it the a pointer pointer of customclass remember that arrays and pointers are deeply connected in c and c++ I can now access the pointer pointer as if it were an array

`CustomClass * FirstEle = Array[0];`

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is very self explanatory !! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually `vectorObject[0]` is a `CustomClass *`, so `&vectorObject[0]` is a `CustomClass **`.

You're making an interesting assumption here, that `vector<>` stores its elements sequentially. You're probably right though, so your code should work.

Edit: As per Ben Voigt's comments, the contiguousness of `vector<>` is guaranteed by the standard, so this method will 100% work.

Comment: +1 for first observation.  The last sentence is wrong though, there's no "probably" about it.  `std::vector` is *required* to use sequential storage, to enable interop with old APIs that accept pointers.

Comment: @BenVoigt, not saying you're wrong, and intuitively it would make sense, but I don't see a requirement for it at http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html. The closest thing I can see is the sequence requirement of elements being arranged in strict linear order, but that's not strong enough.

Comment: @BenVoigt, In fact on http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/complexity.html it explicitly states you can implement `vector<>` using a `list<>`, performance implications aside.

Comment: Read the linked question.  Also note I wrote about `std::vector`, which is similar but not identical to the vector collection template in SGI STL.  SGI documentation is not the definitive reference, the C++ Standard is.

Comment: I read that also, it was a proposal for C++11, not part of the current standard as far as I can tell.

Comment: "The elements of a `vector` are stored contiguously, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <=  n < v.size()`."  Direct quote from 23.3.6.1p1.  You are aware that C++11 is the current Standard, right?  But [the requirement is not new in C++11.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247738/is-it-safe-to-assume-that-stl-vector-storage-is-always-contiguous)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, vectors are required to be consequtive in memory, so the expression "&vectorObject[0]" would return the address of the first element, in which you can point to.