# std::vector to GLvoid*?

Tags: c++, image, opengl, png

I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/) tutorial on OpenGL but instead of loading a raw image I'm using lodePNG.

The problem is that when I cann the function *glTexImage2D* I get an error on the last argument that it only takes a *GLvoid** variable. LodePNG only outputs *std::vector* as the final image data. I cannot find any other resources on the matter.

How would I go about getting this function to work? The error just simply states it doesn't take this data type.

Comment: Perhaps `(GLvoid*)vector.data()`?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate since you're asking about texture data, but the solution is the same as for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048666/opengl-add-vertices/.

Answer (score 7):

[`vector::data()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) is your friend.

You will have to pass the raw data from the vector to the glTexImage function.

```
vector<...> image;
glTexImage2d(..., image.data());
```

Comment: You must also check that the template argument of the vector matches what you send in as the `type`-argument

Comment: Note that the `data()` method was only added with C++11, so it won't be available in older versions of C++.