# Opengl by using vertex buffer objects

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

When I tried to use vertex buffer objects (VBO) to my simple opengl program, I get segmentation fault. First of all let me share part of code which causes seg fault.

```
   //GLuint objectVerticesVBO; type of my VBO
    vector<glm::vec4> objectVertices; // I fill this vector somewhere in the code 
    glGenBuffers(1, &objectVerticesVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, objectVerticesVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  sizeof(glm::vec4)* objectVertices.size(), &objectVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0,0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Now, here is some output that I've printed out:

```
cout<< sizeof(glm::vec4)<<endl;
16
cout<< objectVertices.size()<<endl;
507
```

Is there anyone who knows what causes to segmentation fault ?

Another question is that :

When I add this part also to my code in the renderScene function, I get only an empty screen.

```
   glUseProgram(gProgramShader);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, objectVerticesVBO);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0); 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, objectIndicesVBO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, objectVertices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT,  0);
```

What would be the problem ?

Comment: While it's not an obvious duplicate from just looking at the question, it's the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/24048666/3530129.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `& objectVertices` with `& objectVertices[0]` or `objectVertices.data()` (C++11), in the `glBufferData` call.

The [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container *elements* are contiguous in memory, not the container object itself.

Comment: @Brett_Hale I've editted my question could you look at it one more time ?

Comment: @kemalgunes - you need to setup the buffers, a VAO, and the vertex attributes before `glUseProgram` - assuming the GL program is correct.

Comment: @Brett_Hale, GL program is correct, I had done similar things before as I did like that, without using VAO, I guess my problem is different

Comment: @Brett_Hale in my init function I setup all vertex buffer, indices buffer and normal buffer btw